# Can i remount in the adb shell in android?

Tags: android, shell, command, adb, mount

I am using this command

```
$ adb shell

$ su
-shows permission denied..

$ mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system

But it shows some permission problems 
ie. Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory
```

Thanks!!

Comment: This belongs here: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Depends on the device, whether it's S-ON or S-OFF (HTC devices) and various other things. You may have success booting into recovery and trying there.

Answer (score 0):

You must root your device or unlock your bootloader (if possible) to use mount command